# Value is not coming in back end in spring Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

Hi all i am trying to create one page which have relationship between client and Discharge. I have define one combo box which populate data of client form model and i want that client id in Discharge table but i am not getting value in back end if you inspect it in front end its look good but its null in back end so pls help me to solve this problem.

Here the code,

**DischargeCard.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Discharge_card")

public class DischargeCard {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
private int DischargeId;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "Client_id")
private Client Client_id;

@Column(name = "IPDNo")
private String ipdno;

@Column(name = "DOA")
private Date DOA;

@Column(name = "DOO")
private Date DOO;

@Column(name = "DOD")
private Date DOD;

@Column(name = "DOB")
private Date DOB;

@Column(name = "Age")
private int age;

@Column(name = "Sex")
private String sex;

@Column(name = "Phone")
private String phone;

@Column(name = "Address")
private String Address;

@Column(name = "Diagnosis")
private String diagnosis;

@Column(name = "Treatment")
private String treatment;

@Column(name = "Anesthesia")
private String anesthesia;

@Column(name = "Clinical_Presentation")
private String clinical_presentation;

@Column(name = "Investigation")
private String investigation;

@Column(name = "Given_Treatment")
private String given_treatment;

@Column(name = "Advice_on_Discharge")
private String advice;

< generates setter / getter >
```

**Client.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    int clientId;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please Enter Client Name..." )
    @Column(name = "Name")
    String clientName;


    @Column(name = "ContactName")
    String contactName;

    @NotEmpty(message = " Please Enter Client Address...")
    @Column(name = "Address")
    String clientAddress;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please Enter Client Phone...")
    @Size (min = 10)
    @Pattern (regexp = "[0-9]*")
    @Column(name = "Phone")
    String phone;

    @Email (message = "Please Enter Proper Email Address of Client...")
    @Column(name = "Email")
    String email;

    @NotEmpty (message = "Please Enter Client City...")
    @Column(name = "City")
    String city;

    @NotEmpty (message = "Please Enter Client Zip Code...")
    @Size (min = 6)
    @Pattern (regexp = "[0-9]*")
    @Column(name = "Zip")
    String zip;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please Enter Client State...")
    @Column(name = "State")
    String state;

    @NotEmpty (message = "Please Enter Client Country...")
    @Column(name = "Country")
    String country;


    @Column(name = "Private")
    String privateNote;


    @Column(name = "Other")
    String otherNote;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Company_id")
    private Company company;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Client_id")
    private Set<Invoice> invoice;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Client_ID")
    private Set<Estimate> estimate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Client_id")
    private Set<DischargeCard> discharges;

    < generated setter / getter >
```

**DischargeCardController.java**

```
@Controller
public class DischargeCardController {
    @Autowired
    DischargeCardService ds;
    @Autowired
    ClientService service;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/dishcharge", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showClientDetailsPage(Model m, HttpServletRequest req) {
        m.addAttribute("dischargecard", new DischargeCard());
        m.addAttribute("actionURL", "saveCard");
        List<Client> obj = service.getAll("");
        m.addAttribute("clientList", obj);

         List<String> clientlist = new ArrayList<>();
         for(Client c : obj)
         {
             clientlist.add(c.getClientName().toString());
         }
        m.addAttribute("client_name_list",clientlist);
        return "dischargeCard";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveCard", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveCompanyDetails(@ModelAttribute("DischargeCard")DischargeCard dc, BindingResult result,
            HttpServletRequest req) {
        String redirectTo = "";
        /*if(result.hasErrors())
        {
            redirectTo = "dischargeCard";
            return redirectTo;
        }
        else
        {*/
        ds.saveData(dc);
        redirectTo = "redirect:dishcharge";
        return redirectTo;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchDischargeCard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showUsersPage() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("searchDischargeCard");
        List<Client> obj = service.getAll("");
        mv.addObject("clientList", obj);

         List<String> clientlist = new ArrayList<>();
         for(Client c : obj)
         {
             clientlist.add(c.getClientName().toString());
         }
        mv.addObject("client_name_list",clientlist);
        mv.addObject("DischargeList",ds.getAll(""));
        return mv;
    }

}
```

**DischargeCard.jsp**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>
<jsp:include page="menu.jsp"></jsp:include>

<!-- BEGIN Content -->
<div id="main-content">
    <!-- BEGIN Page Title -->
    <div class="page-title">
        <div>
            <h1>
                <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> Add Dishcharge Card
            </h1>
            <h4>Add data of new Discharge Card</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END Page Title -->

    <!-- BEGIN Breadcrumb -->
    <div id="breadcrumbs">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <a href="index.html">Home</a> <span
                class="divider"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></li>
            <li class="active">Discharge</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- END Breadcrumb -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box box-pink">
                <div class="box-title">
                    <h3>
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Discharge Card
                    </h3>
                    <div class="box-tool">
                        <a data-action="collapse" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                        <a data-action="close" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-content">
                    <%-- <form action="#" > --%>
                    <form:form action="${actionURL}" class="form-horizontal"
                        id="wizard-validation" method="post"
                        modelAttribute="dischargecard">
                        <form:hidden path="DischargeId" id="DischargeId" />
                        <div class="form-wizard" id="form-wizard-2">
                            <ul class="row steps steps-fill">
                                <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3"><a href="#tab2-1"
                                    data-toggle="tab" class="step active"> <span class="number">1</span>
                                        <span class="desc"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Client
                                            Details</span>
                                </a></li>
                                <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3"><a href="#tab2-2"
                                    data-toggle="tab" class="step"> <span class="number">2</span>
                                        <span class="desc"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                            Treatment Details</span>
                                </a></li>
                                <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3"><a href="#tab2-3"
                                    data-toggle="tab" class="step"> <span class="number">3</span>
                                        <span class="desc"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Photo's</span>
                                </a></li>
                                <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3"><a href="#tab2-4"
                                    data-toggle="tab" class="step"> <span class="number">4</span>
                                        <span class="desc"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Confirm</span>
                                </a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="progress progress-striped">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab2-1">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="firstname2"
                                            class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Client Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <!-- <input type="text" name="firstname2" id="firstname2"
                                             class="form-control" data-rule-required="true"> -->
                                            <%-- <form:select path="Client_id"
                                                class="form-control chosen" data-rule-required="true"
                                                style="border-radius: 8px;"
                                                data-placeholder="Choose a client" tabindex="1">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <c:forEach var="client" items="${clientList}">

                                                    <form:option value="${client.clientId}">${client.clientName}</form:option>

                                                </c:forEach>
                                            </form:select> --%>

                                            <form:select path="Client_id" items="${clientList}"
                                                itemValue="clientId" itemLabel="clientName" />

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="firstname2"
                                            class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">IPD Number</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <form:input path="ipdno" name="ipdno" type="text"
                                                class="form-control" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Date of
                                            Admission</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <form:input path="DOA" name="doa"
                                                class="form-control date-picker" id="dp1" size="16"
                                                type="text" value="" />


                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-group col-sm-5 col-lg-2">
                                            <a class="input-group-addon" href="#"><i
                                                class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></a>
                                            <form:input path="DOA" name="doa"
                                                class="form-control timepicker-default" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Date of
                                            Operation</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <form:input path="DOO" name="doo"
                                                class="form-control date-picker" id="dp1" size="16"
                                                type="text" value="" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-group col-sm-5 col-lg-2">
                                            <a class="input-group-addon" href="#"><i
                                                class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></a>
                                            <form:input path="DOO" name="doo"
                                                class="form-control timepicker-default" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Date of
                                            Discharge</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <form:input path="DOD" name="dod"
                                                class="form-control date-picker" id="dp1" size="16"
                                                type="text" value="" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-group col-sm-5 col-lg-2">
                                            <a class="input-group-addon" href="#"><i
                                                class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></a>
                                            <form:input path="DOD" name="dod"
                                                class="form-control timepicker-default" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Date of
                                            Birth</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <form:input path="DOB" name="dob"
                                                class="form-control date-picker" id="dp1" size="16"
                                                type="text" value="" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="lastname2" class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Age</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <form:input path="age" name="Age" type="text" id="lastname2"
                                                class="form-control" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Radio
                                            Buttons</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-10 controls">
                                            <label class="radio-inline"> <form:radiobutton
                                                    path="sex" name="optionsRadios2" value="Male" /> Male
                                            </label> <label class="radio-inline"> <form:radiobutton
                                                    path="sex" name="optionsRadios2" value="Female" /> Female
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="firstname2"
                                            class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Phone</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <form:input path="phone" name="Phone" type="text"
                                                class="form-control" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Address</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-5 controls">
                                            <form:textarea path="Address" name="address"
                                                class="form-control" rows="4"></form:textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Diagnosis</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-5 controls">
                                            <form:textarea path="diagnosis" name="Diagnosis"
                                                class="form-control" rows="4"></form:textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Treatment</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-5 controls">
                                            <form:textarea path="treatment" name="Treatment"
                                                class="form-control" rows="4"></form:textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="firstname2"
                                            class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Anesthesia</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <form:input path="anesthesia" name="Anesthesia" type="text"
                                                class="form-control" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Clinical
                                            Presentation</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-5 controls">
                                            <form:textarea path="clinical_presentation"
                                                name="clinicalpresentation" class="form-control" rows="4"></form:textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Investigation</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-5 controls">
                                            <form:textarea path="investigation" name="Investigation"
                                                class="form-control" rows="4"></form:textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Given
                                            Treatment</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-5 controls">
                                            <form:textarea path="given_treatment" name="giventreatment"
                                                class="form-control" rows="4"></form:textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Treatment
                                            Advice on Discharge</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-5 controls">
                                            <form:textarea path="advice" name="Advice"
                                                class="form-control" rows="4"></form:textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="country2" class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Country</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <input type="text" name="country2" id="country2"
                                                class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="city2" class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">City</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <input type="text" name="city2" id="city2"
                                                class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <%-- <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Gender</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <label class="radio-inline"> 
                                            <form:radiobutton path="sex" name="gender" value="Male" /> Male
                                            </label> <label class="radio-inline"> 
                                            <form:radiobutton path="sex" name="gender" value="Female" /> Female
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> --%>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="textarea2" class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">More
                                            info</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <textarea name="textarea2" id="textarea2" rows="5"
                                                class="form-control"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">First
                                            Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <span class="text">Penny</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">last
                                            Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <span class="text">Rodrigez</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Gender</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <span class="text">Female</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Username</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <span class="text">PennyRod</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3 controls">
                                            <span class="text">pennyrod@domain.com</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn button-previous">Back</a> <a
                                        href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary button-next">Continue</a>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success button-submit">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form:form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END Main Content -->
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
```